# Autocomplete white background not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have a white background where the user can select a item in the autocomplete however I have my header image that keeps repeating.

Here is a image of my probleme

[image: Background image not white]

As you can see I highlighted in blue every suggestion. However I get the background image for each suggestion instead of having a simple white background.

Here is my html

```
<header>
    <h1>
        <a href="/">
            <span class="texte-cache">Sel gras</span>
        </a>
    </h1>
    <section class="section-recherche">
        <?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $rechercheErr = "";
        $recherche  = "";
        $rechercheValid = false;
        ?>

        <form method="get" action="../pages/recherche.php">
            <label for="recherche" class="lblRechercher">Rechercher</label>
            <div class="recherche">
                <input type="search" name="recherche" id="recherche" placeholder="Rechercher..." value="<?php echo $recherche; ?>" />
                <span class="error"> <?php echo $rechercheErr; ?></span>
                <button title="Rechercher" class="button-recherche" id="buttonRecherche" name="submit"><i class="material-icons-white">search</i></button>
            </div>
            <div id="div-suggestions" class="suggestions masquer"></div>
        </form>
    </section>

</header>
```

And here is my css that cause the probleme

```
/*Exemple when screen is large*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  header a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 270px;
    background-size: 100% 120%;
    background-image: url(../images/logo-long.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
  }
}
```

Here is the css for the autcomplete.

```
.afficher {
  display:block;
}

.masquer {
  display:none;
}

.suggestions {
  background-color:white;
  width:194px;
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-image: none;
}

.suggestions ul {
  padding-left:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.suggestions ul li:hover {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

I have tried to add

```
  background-image: none;
```

However it did not work. What can I do to fix this problem thank you for your help

I have added a JsFiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/L9afb2u0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I used

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  header h1 a {
```

instead of

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  header a {
```

Answer (score 1):

the code is a little hard to understand, but basically, remove background image and add an img element on the html doc.

```js
var scriptSug =
{
    "divSuggestions" : null
};

function viderElement(element) {
    while (element.lastChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
    }
}

 /**
 * Appelée lors d'un clic dans la fenêtre
 */
function gererClicFenetre(evenement) {
    var clicDedans = scriptSug.divSuggestions.contains(evenement.target);
    window.console.log("Clic dans la zone cliquable ? " + clicDedans);

    if (!clicDedans) {
        viderElement(scriptSug.divSuggestions);
        scriptSug.divSuggestions.className = "suggestions masquer";
        document.removeEventListener("click", gererClicFenetre);
    }
}


/**
 * Pour demander les suggestions au site web.
 *
 * On devrait procéder par AJAX pour récupérer les suggestions, mais
 * elles sont "hard-codés" pour la démo.
 */
function afficherSuggestions() {
    viderElement(scriptSug.divSuggestions);

    scriptSug.divSuggestions.className = "suggestions afficher";

    var elemListe = document.createElement("ul");
    scriptSug.divSuggestions.appendChild(elemListe);

    for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        var itemListe = document.createElement("li");
        // TODO : ne pas mettre de .innerHTML dans votre TP
        itemListe.innerHTML = 
            "<a href='http://www.google.ca'>Suggestion " + i + "</a>";

        elemListe.appendChild(itemListe);
    }

    // Ajout d'un événement sur tout le document (la fenêtre)
    document.addEventListener("click", gererClicFenetre, false);
 }


/**
 * Appelée lors de l'initialisation de la page
 */
function initialisation() {
    scriptSug.divSuggestions = document.getElementById("div-suggestions");

    document.getElementById("recherche").addEventListener("input", afficherSuggestions, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", initialisation, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8"; 
/* Créé par Junior Corenbach et MINH NGUYEN */

html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#page{
    background-color: #eFeFeF;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aa0000;  
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DB9900;  
}

p{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
header{
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
}

main{
    margin-left: 30px;
    contain: layout;
}

footer{
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/* || En tête */
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
h2{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h4{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-align: center;
}


.afficher {
  display:block;
}

.masquer {
  display:none;
}

.suggestions {
  background-color:white;
  width:194px;
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.suggestions ul {
  padding-left:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.suggestions ul li:hover {
  background-color:lightblue;
}

/* || Page connection */
#connection div{
    margin: 10px;
}

input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #DB9900; /* Green */
    border: #7F5900 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50%;
}

input[type=button], input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #C08600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button], input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: #A57300;
}

.error{
    color: red;
}

.recherche{
  display: flex; 
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.gallery-link{
  color: #111;  
}

.gallery-link:hover{
  color: #DB9900;
}

/*min ici pour tout ecran plus grand est une image*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  header a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 270px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    header a {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      height: 270px;
      background-size: 100% 120%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  header a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 270px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  header a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 270px;
  }
}

.texte-cache {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
}

  /******************************************/
  /*************** MENU***********************/
  /******************************************/
.menu-principal {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #DB9900;
  }
  
  .menu-principal li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  .menu-principal li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .menu-principal li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
  }

  /******************************************/
  /***********ERREUR*************************/
  /******************************************/
  .imag-erreur{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header-erreur{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1000%;
    color:#DB9900;
    border: #111111;
  }
  .erreur-text-large{
    font-size: 300%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .erreur-text-petit{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    color:#111;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .icon-page-acces{
    text-align: center;
  }
  /******************************************/
  /***********GALERY*************************/
  /******************************************/
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;

}


.material-icons-yellow {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #DB9900;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;

}

.material-icons-yellow-large {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #DB9900;
  font-size: 900%;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  vertical-align: top;

}

.material-icons-white {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;

}

.material-icons-white-small {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;

}


.material-icons-red {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #aa0000;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;

}

div#gallery-large {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#gallery-auto{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.titre-gallery-auto-section{
  min-height: 50px;
}

.gallery-hiden{
  display: none;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
}

div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
  }
  
  .imageRecette {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  div.desc {
    text-align: center;
  }

  div.desc p{
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
.list-recettes{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  float: left;
}

.titre-gallery{
  min-height: 150px;
}
  /******************************************/
  /******************************************/
  /******************************************/


  .image-details-recette{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .deuxieme-section-recette{
    padding-top: 2%;
    clear: both;
  }



input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]  {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=search]  {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section-recherche{
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  padding: 0%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 10px;
}

hr{
  margin: 1%;
}

#buttonRecherche{
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
}

#button-commenter{
  width: 120px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

#button-gallery-precedent{
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  display: none;
}

#button-gallery-suivant{
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  display: none;
}

.btn-gallery{
  text-align:center;
}

.image-gallery-auto{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

textarea{
  width: 99%;
  resize: none;
}

.section-commentaire{
  margin-left: 2%;  
}

.pied li{ 
     list-style-type: none;
}

.pied-couriel li{
  list-style-type: none;
}

button{
  background-color: #DB9900;
  border: #7F5900 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
}

.lblRechercher{
  display: inline;
  color:white;
  font-size: 100%;
}

 a{
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid reD;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style="">
    <div id="page">
        
<header>
    <h1>
        <a href="/">
        <img src="https://static.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/opensource.gif" />
            <span class="texte-cache">Sel gras</span>
        </a>
    </h1>
    <section class="section-recherche">
        <form method="get" action="../pages/recherche.php">
            <label for="recherche" class="lblRechercher">Rechercher</label>
            <div class="recherche">
                <input type="search" name="recherche" id="recherche" placeholder="Rechercher..." value="" />
                <span class="error"> </span>
                <button title="Rechercher" class="button-recherche" id="buttonRecherche" name="submit"><i class="material-icons-white">search</i></button>
            </div>
            <div id="div-suggestions" class="suggestions masquer"></div>
        </form>
    </section>
    
    </header>
    </div>
</body>    

</html>
```

Comment: I have added the properties you have suggested in .suggestions however it still does not work

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach i dont have a php environment to test this, but you're saying that the drop down displays your background image?

Comment: Yes every li displays the background

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach try hard coding it into your document like this: <li style="background: white;">

Comment: I have tried it in chrome debugger but it still does not change the background color.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach areyou able to publish and post a link so i can debug?

Comment: Yes I have create a JsFiddle however it i my first time. Does it work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/L9afb2u0/

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach updated answer, jsfiddle works great!

Comment: This solution won't work for me since I have different images depending on the size of the screen so my image does not look deformed.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach you are facing the problem completely wrong, what you are talking about is responsive web-design. this is handled with media queries. you want to keep the aspect ratio not distort the image

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `<span class="YourClass">Suggestion 0</span>` inside the a href and give a different css to the span then you can modify only the suggestions 0 etc

Answer (score 0):

You should learn a bit more for how css selectors works.
Since **header a** says, any **a** in **header** should have next styles (and you dropdawn is part of header and has **a** in it) it inherits that styles.

To be more specific you could add some class for yours a in header (**a.link** for example), and separate styles in that way.